# What is the difference between Netsuite Bundle Copy and Push?

Tags: copy, installation, bundle, push, netsuite

I am trying to figure out a better way to transfer bundles within our company and to multiple clients account. Which one will be the better way to install a bundle and later update it - Copy or Push? What are the limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy is intended for versioning, deprecation and release testing.
You can think about copy as Forking a Project.
When coping a bundle, it will get a new bundle number and will appear on the bundle list.

If you want to move the bundle to client accounts, you have to install/push it on their accounts, never copy.